# Hash of ref functions inside Perl module

Tags: perl, hash, reference, module

I am trying to write a module that should be able to invoke specific methods depending on the content of a variable. I decided to use a hash mapping these names to function references. I have written some proof-of-concept code to see whether this would work, and I bumped into some problems along the way.

I am having problems with the reference function calls not being able to access my $self->... data members.

Below is the actual copy-paste proof-of-concept example to display the problem I experience.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

package My::Test;

sub new {
    my $class = shift;
    my $self = {};

    $self->{_currentType} = undef;
    $self->{_currentData} = undef;
    $self->{_mapping} = undef;

    return bless $self, $class;
}

# Setup the mapping
sub createMapping {
    my $self = shift;

    my %mapping = ( 'mapping.1' => \&My::Test::handler1,
                    'mapping.2' => \&My::Test::handler2,
                    'mapping.3' => \&My::Test::handler3, );

    $self->{_mapping} = \%mapping;
}

# This is the main entrypoint for actual processing where the appropriate handler function is invoked.
sub startMeUp {
    my ($self, $mapType, $someDataToHandle) = @_;

    $self->{_currentType} = $mapType;
    $self->{_currentData} = $someDataToHandle;

    # Now call this function
    $self->{_mapping}->{$mapType}->();
}

# These functions below gets called, but the values of $self are not retained. Why?
sub handler1 {
    my $self = shift;
    print "I am a handler for $self->{_currentType}!\n";
}

sub handler2 {
    my $self = shift;
    print "I am a handler for $self->{_currentType}!\n";
}

sub handler3 {
    my $self = shift;
    print "I am a handler for $self->{_currentType}!\n";
}

sub manualFunction {
    my $self = shift;
    print "I am a manual call, I am $self->{_currentType}!\n";
}

1;
```

The above module is then invoked via a simple caller script like so:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use My::Test;

my $test = My::Test->new();
$test->createMapping();

# We want to try to execute the handler2 function (mapping.2 is mapped to handler2 via createMapping).
# The function call works but when done this way, I cannot use
# $self->{someVariableName} to access module members as I'd like.
$test->startMeUp('mapping.2');

# The follow will work.
$test->manualFunction();
```

Running the perl script yields the following result:

```
% perl test.pl                                                                                                                               
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at My/Test.pm line 48.
I am a handler for !
I am a manual call, I am mapping.2!
```

I am having problems finding a solution as to why the **startMeUp** function which invokes references via the hash table does not retain the values contained in **$self->{some class member variable here}**.

I have tried to search SO about this but have not been able to find a question/answer about this specific problem.

I am not sure whether what I am trying to do is simply not possible in this context or whether I am simply doing it wrong, so I hope some of you here could point me in the right direction.

(Of course it's overkill to implement a solution like this for only three elements, but in the actual implementation there would be significantly more, and I would rather avoid having to write a good screenfull of if-elsif statements, and it's also a good exercise).

Thank you in advance!

Best regards,
Klaus

Comment: What @dgw wrote or, `$self->{_mapping}{$mapType}->($self);`

Comment: That `uninitialized value` is a big alarm bell to me - looks like `self` is undefined. I _think_ that'll be because you're `mapping` a reference to a sub, rather than an OO call.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change your mapping setup from

```
sub createMapping {
    my $self = shift;

    my %mapping = ( 'mapping.1' => \&My::Test::handler1,
                    'mapping.2' => \&My::Test::handler2,
                    'mapping.3' => \&My::Test::handler3, );

    $self->{_mapping} = \%mapping;
}
```

to

```
sub createMapping {
    my $self = shift;

    my %mapping = ( 'mapping.1' => sub { $self->handler1 } ,
                    'mapping.2' => sub { $self->handler2 } ,
                    'mapping.3' => sub { $self->handler3 } );

    $self->{_mapping} = \%mapping;
}
```

your test script will work.

The `&My::Test::handler1` will call the `handler1` as simple function, not as object methods.

Comment: Tested and it works perfectly. Thank you very much for the example and explanation!